# Jquery ID selector doesnt work with a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, undefined

I've read a billion questions like this, but never found an answer yet.

Anyway, when I type

```
var variableContainingID = "header";
var div = $("#"+variableContainingID);
```

It returns 'undefined'

But when I type

```
var variableContainingID = "header";
var div = $('[id^="'+variableContainingID+'"]');
```

It works fine. 
Any ideas why?

UPDATE

```
var json = '{"divs":['
var children = $(".parent_container > div");
var idArray = [];
var numArray = [];
for (var x=0; x<children.length; x++) {
    var eleid = $(children[x]).attr("id");
    idArray.push('"'+eleid+'"');
    numArray.push(x+1);
}
var idString = idArray.join(",");
var numString = numArray.join(",");
json += idString;
json += '],"number":['+numString+']}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
for (x in obj["divs"]) {
    var div = $('[id^="'+obj["divs"][x]+'"]');
}
```

Do you think the double quotes could be throwing it off?

Comment: Do you actually have an element with an `id="header"`?

Comment: Are you typing this into the Chrome dev console?  It returns `undefined` when a variable is defined.

Comment: It does work... http://jsfiddle.net/qsjrP/ we will probably need to see more of your code as I dont think the declaration is the problem...

Comment: Are you sure your id of header is just 'header' and not 'headerMain' or 'header '?

Comment: Is your id headersomething?

Comment: And is the ID unique!

Answer (score 4):

As you wrote in your question:

```
var div = $("#"+variableContainingID);
var div = $('[id^="'+variableContainingID+'"]');
```

These two lines are not identical. The first one, will select an element with `id` of `header`. The second one,
selects elements that have the specified `id` with a value beginning exactly with a given string (`header`).

So if you have an element like this:

```
<div id="headerHere"></div>
```

The first one (`$("#"+variableContainingID)`) can't select it, but the second one (`$('[id^="'+variableContainingID+'"]')`) can select that element.
**This is because you used `^=` in your selector**. See jQuery API: [Attribute Starts With Selector (name^="value")](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

It's worth to see all `attribute` selectors in jQuery.

- [Attribute Selectors in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely not the problem :)

Comment: @NateL If this is not problem then better to post HTML also, with out seeing your Id its not possible to give you exact solution .